# SoundCloud Widget External Control iOS issue

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I have found a bug using the external controls for the html5 widget on iOS, i have tested with iphone and ipad. The controls inside the widget work ok. However on my clients site http://www.bushytunes.net and the widget api playground http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html the external controls run an error.

Here is what the console from the widget playground prints:

```
SC.Widget.Events.PLAY {"loadedProgress":null,"currentPosition":0,"relativePosition":0}
SC.Widget.Events.PAUSE {"loadedProgress":null,"currentPosition":0,"relativePosition":0}
SC.Widget.Events.PLAY {"loadedProgress":null,"currentPosition":0,"relativePosition":0}
SC.Widget.Events.PLAY {"loadedProgress":null,"currentPosition":0,"relativePosition":0}
SC.Widget.Events.PLAY {"loadedProgress":null,"currentPosition":0,"relativePosition":0}
SC.Widget.Events.READY {}
Loading...
```

Thanks, James

Comment: Hey James, we'll look at this ASAP.

Comment: Hi again, it seems like this might require a more complex solution, I'll update you when this is resolved.

Comment: @gryzzly/ jamesbat Can I have the sample source code....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: iOS 6 should work with a limitation of a call to play to be init by user action, iOS5 and below probably won't get a fix.

We'll try to resolve this with some kind of a hack, but most probably this won't get a proper solution any time soon.

SoundCloud Widget is using HTML5 Audio to play sounds on iOS. There are two limitations on starting playback in iOS:

1. Playback **must** be started by user action (so within event handler)
2. The call to `audio.play` method has to be within synchronous call stack of that event handler.

This means, that this works:

```
document.querySelector('.play-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    audioController.play();
}, false);
```

But this doesn't:

```
document.querySelector('.play-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        audioController.play();
    }, 500);
}, false);
```

Cross-domain communication between iframes is only possible in asynchronous manner. Our implementation is using `postMessage` DOM API, but even older techniques such as Fragment Identifier Messaging (FIM) that is using `location.hash` are asynchronous. This means we don't currently see a way of enabling playback through API for iOS5 and below (as there is also no Flash fallback).

<del>However, there are also good news: **iOS6 has dropped the limitation No2**. This means that as long as the API call to `play` is called by user action, you'll be able to play sounds. Even though the communication between your parent window and widgets' iframe is still async.</del> Unfortunately iOS hasn't dropped this limitation.

I hope this helps and I'll update this answer in case we find a proper workaround.

My suggestion would be to build your own custom player with a library like [Audio5JS](http://zohararad.github.com/audio5js/) or [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) in case controlling playback on iOS is crucial for your app.

You can see vague description of what I am talking about on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html) resource.

Comment: Are you sure the "dropped the limitation No2" part not actually correct? I wrote [this simple test](http://mrcoles.com/media/test2/soundcloud/), which works fine on my laptop, but fails on my iphone (4s on iOS 6). I'm hoping I missed something...

Comment: Unfortunately, I must stand corrected :( I'm not sure now why I wrote this and I just tested this myself. There was a gossip around the internet about this working at least when you are on *wi-fi*, but even that is not the case. I'll edit this answer.

Comment: thx for the answer, I had written [a test](http://mrcoles.com/media/test2/soundcloud/) to try it out too. It's a bit frustrating that the play event gets triggered and the button changes to look like it's playing. As you said, it looks like I'd have to go with a custom player to get more control in iOS.

Comment: Hi @gryzzly, I got the same problem on http://hvsr.net/ 
Anything is changed from the time you gave this answer? Thanks.

Comment: @franz976 not that I know of, unfortunately.

Comment: @gryzzly thanx for your kind answer. I tried Audio5JS but on mobile it still requires user action to works. I'm basically working at a playlist-site and I'd like to stream a new track when the previous one has endend. On desktop it works, on mobile it doesn't. Even with Audio5JS. Any hint?

Comment: @gryzzly to be clerear, I create a jsfiddle. It's ok for me if the user click PLAY on the first track, but then the player should move to the next song. Thank you in advance.
http://jsfiddle.net/franz976/pyt5k0ma/

Answer (score 1):

I can't completely tell if @gryzzly is trying to say this, but **the Widget API's external controls are completely broken on mobile**.  The answer does explain why -- you can't synchronously tell the iFrame to play the sound, but it is my understanding that proper iframe.contentWindow calls would be synchronous?  I may be wrong.

Try directing your mobile phone to the widget API playground: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html

Even there it doesn't actually play unless you press the orange button.

Pretty irritating since there's no application to get around the streaming API limit either.  There seems to be literally no way to get a site that may experience more than 15,000 requests/plays per day to work with SoundCloud on mobile.  I just want continuous music playback.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a workaround for this?  I can't figure it out.  I have to press the orange button before any of my controls do anything....

Comment: You have to use the streaming API