# HTML5 widget .play() method not working

Tags: ios6, soundcloud, ipod-touch

SC.Widget('id_of_widget').play(); doesn't seem to work on iOS (v6 in pod touch). I've been trying to get it to work on my own site, (http://www.fromabrokenheart.com/119) but couldn't. All is fine in other browsers I have tried on windows.

I then tried the html widget playground (http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html) and that is not working on my ipod touch either. The play button above the console does not work.

In the console on the playground, I get continual "loadedProgress": null.... errors... see attached screenshot... I could not see the full error there...

any thoughts?

Nick

Comment: Hey Nick, we are aware of the problem with API access to play method on iOS – I've written a summary of the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420228/soundcloud-widget-external-control-ios-issue/13569799#13569799 I think we might have a fix for iOS6 at least, and I'll update this question when we deploy the fix.

Comment: thanks for the response... good to know it wasn't my bad coding after all :-) thanks for all you're doing with soundcloud. loving it!