# How to get SoundCloud iframe API working on iPhone?

Tags: soundcloud

I'm trying to get the SoundCloud iframe API up and running on an iPhone, but I'm running into issues with getting it to play. I've prepared a JSFiddle to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/aj3Pw/1/. What I'm attempting to accomplish is to simply add a play button to trigger the widget to start playing. Loading the example up in your browser, you'll notice that everything works fine (the play button will start playing the widget). However, loading that same example up in an iPhone, the widget will not play. The 'Play' button will change to a 'Pause' button, but the audio never starts playing. In addition, the 'ready' event seems to never fire on the iPhone either. Any ideas as to why this isn't working on an iPhone?

Code from the above JSFiddle:

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('#player');
var sc = SC.Widget(iframe);

sc.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
    var d = document.createTextNode('Ready');
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(d);
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    sc.play();
});
```

The markup:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F7659975" id="player"></iframe>

<button id="play">Play</button>
```

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try this again:
On iPhone Simulator and actual iPhone, if you hit the Orange play button it plays. If you then pause it using the same orange button, it pauses.

At this point, you can hit your play button, and it works, this works on iPhone and iPhone Simulator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SoundCloud Widget External Control iOS issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420228/soundcloud-widget-external-control-ios-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: iOS 6 should work with a limitation of a call to play to be init by user action, iOS5 and below probably won't get a fix.

Full answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13569799/236135